# Escaping variables in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following code to create a mysql database via command line

```
dbcommand="create database $dbname;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname.* TO $dbuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpassw';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql -u root -p$pass -e "$dbcommand"
```

It works fine most of the time but if $dbname / $dbuser consist of a special character like a dash (`-`) the `$dbcommand` fails.

How can i fix it to work even with special characters

Comment: would using the escape character \ not work?
Example from http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html :



`franky ~> date=20021226

franky ~> echo $date
20021226

franky ~> echo \$date
$date`

Comment: `the $dbcommand fails` With what error?

Comment: @schil227 ...Will try this on a linux server and report back

Comment: @Qix i mean the database don't get created so i assume that `$dbcommand` is failing

Comment: There is nothing you have to escape. As long as you provide valid database/table names, then your command will work fine. If you are using any characters that will cause expansion in your bash script i.e. `*`, then you need to validate your variables contain what you think they contain. Lastly use `mysql -u root -p${pass} -Be "$dbcommand"` The `-B` is for batch mode which disables interactive behavior.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so you mean i just have to `-B` to make command foolproof.`myblog-wp` is a valid database name btw

Comment: You are correct -- see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql only ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore) can be included in database names **unquoted**. See: [**9.2 Schema Object Names**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) Permitted characters in **quoted** identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000. Id. The identifier quote character is the **backtick** (“`”). Id. So in your case you need:

```
dbcommand="create database \`$dbname\`;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`$dbname\`.* TO $dbuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpassw';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql -u root -p${pass} -Be "$dbcommand"
```

If for some reason the `\` characters are stripped on assignment to `dbcommand`, then use:

```
mysql -u root -p${pass} -Be "create database \`$dbname\`;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`$dbname\`.* TO $dbuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpassw';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

**example:**

```
$ mysql -Be "create database \`myblog-wp\`;"
$ mysql -Be "show databases;"
Database
information_schema
mmedia
myblog-wp
mysql
performance_schema
```

**NOTE:** In bash, you have to escape the backticks with `\` to prevent them from being considered a request for command execution. If it were me, I'd name my database `weblogwp` and not have to worry about the backtick quotes :)

Comment: Do i need to add the backticks with `$dbuser` and and `$dbpassw`.You never know what the user may enter:P

Comment: Only if they contain something other than ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore). I would also **send one command at a time** in case one fails -- you know which one did it.

Comment: `-` forms part of ascii so it should have worked.Maybe the variable $dbname contained a leading space which i think might have cause command to fail.What you think ?